# how to generate grouped result in R?

Tags: r

Here is my data

```
> str(myData)
'data.frame':   500 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ PassengerId: int  1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...
 $ Survived   : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Pclass     : int  3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ Name       : Factor w/ 891 levels "Abbing, Mr. Anthony",..: 109 191 16 559 520 629 417 581 732 96 ...
 $ Sex        : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Age        : num  22 38 35 NA 54 2 27 14 4 58 ...
 $ SibSp      : int  1 1 0 0 0 3 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Parch      : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 ...
 $ Ticket     : Factor w/ 681 levels "110152","110413",..: 524 597 473 276 86 396 345 133 617 39 ...
 $ Fare       : num  7.25 71.28 8.05 8.46 51.86 ...
 $ Cabin      : Factor w/ 147 levels "A10","A14","A16",..: NA 82 NA NA 130 NA NA NA 146 50 ...
 $ Embarked   : Factor w/ 3 levels "C","Q","S": 3 1 3 2 3 3 3 1 3 3 ...
```

I have to generate 2 results

1.grouped by title and pclass of each passenger like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N5sp.jpg)

2.display table of missing age counts grouped by title and pclass like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSUzn.jpg)

but when I used what I know both resulted like below

```
> myData$Name = as.character(myData$Name)
> table_words = table(unlist(strsplit(myData$Name, "\\s+")))
> sort(table_words [grep('\\.',names(table_words))], decreasing=TRUE)

      Mr.     Miss.      Mrs.   Master.       Dr.      Rev.      Col.     Capt. Countess.      Don. 
      289        99        76        20         5         3         2         1         1         1 
       L.     Mlle.      Mme.      Sir. 
        1         1         1         1 
> library(stringr)
> tb = cbind(myData$Age, str_match(myData$Name, "[a-zA-Z]+\\."))
> table(tb[is.na(tb[,1]),2])

    Dr. Master.   Miss.     Mr.    Mrs. 
      1       3      18      62       7
```

basically I have to return tables not by total amount like I did above but to display by 3 different rows sorting by Pclass int which the total of 3rows would still be the same as total amount(myTitle = Pclass int 1 / 2 / 3 in 'myData')

so for example, the result of image 1 would mean that Capt. exists only 1 by int 1 unber Pclass data.

how should i sort the total amount by Pclass int 1,2,and 3?

Comment: Please stop using "RStudio" when you are just asking plain R questions. Only use it if you have questions about the RStudio interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell with no data provided (though I think that it comes from the Titanic dataset on Kaggle).

I think the first thing to do is to create a new factor with `Title` as you want to make analysis with it. I'd do something like:

```
# Extract title from name and make it a factor
dat$Title <- gsub(".* (.*)\\. .*$", "\\1", as.character(dat$Name))
dat$Title <- factor(dat$Title)
```

You'll need to check that it works with your data.

Once you have the `Title` factor you can use `ddply` from the `plyr` library and make the first table (grouped by `Title` and `Pclass` of each passenger):

```
library(plyr)
# Number of occurences
classTitle <- ddply(dat, c('Pclass', 'Title'), summarise,
                    count=length(Name))
# Convert to wide format
classTitle <- reshape(classTitle, idvar = "Title", timevar = "Pclass",
                      direction = "wide")
# Fill NA's with 0
classTitle[is.na(classTitle)] <- 0
```

Almost the same thing for your second requirement (display table of missing age counts grouped by `Title` and `Pclass`):

```
# Number of NA in Age
countNA <- ddply(dat, c('Pclass', 'Title'), summarise,
                    na=sum(is.na(Age)))
# Convert to wide format
countNA <- reshape(countNA, idvar = "Title", timevar = "Pclass",
                      direction = "wide")
# Fill NA's with 0
countNA[is.na(countNA)] <- 0
```